# Quotient space of $\Bbb R^2 / {\sim} \approx T^2$ defined by $\mathbf x \sim \mathbf y \iff \mathbf x=\mathbf y A^n$

Tags: general-topology

Below is my homework problem.

But I cannot even think of a vague idea for a proof. 
Can anyone give some idea for the proof?

Let $A$ be an invertible $2 \times 2$ matrix with entries in $\mathbb R$.

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\Bbb R^2$ by

$(x_1, y_1) \sim (x_2, y_2) \iff (x_1,y_1) = (x_2,y_2)A^n$, for some $n \in \Bbb Z$.

Show that $\Bbb R^2/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to the torus $T^2$.

Comment: This can't be quite right, since rotations $A$ of finite order will produce a quotient that is essentially the plane again (disregarding some roughness at $0$). Maybe $A$ was required to have two real eigenvalues?

Comment: Typesetting note: The "$\sim$" symbol usually represents a binary operation and therefore has spacing before it and after it, of a sort not appropriate when writing $\mathbb R/{\sim}\approx T^2$.  Just putting writing {\sim} instead of \sim solves that.  (I changed it accordingly.)

Comment: More is wrong. If $A$ is the identity, what happens? And, in general, the origin causes problems.

Comment: The argument is just the problem says. In case of $A=I$, $\mathbb R^2 / \sim \approx \mathbb R^2 \approx T^2$. Which seems doesn't make sense. I should chech the validity of the problem. Thank guys!!!